# Entity framework migration, denormalise existing data and introduce foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing database (EF code first) which has data in a table (`table1`) that represents an enum (c#), then another table (`table2`) that has a column containing one of the values of the enum.

What I need to do is denormalise `table1` so that it has foreign key to `table2` (the enum values)

In terms of the entities I started with:

```
public class EnvironmentTypes 
{
    [Key]
    public int EnvironmentTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

for `table1`

and

```
public class EnvironmentDetails
{
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public EnvironmentType EnvironmentType { get; set; }
}
```

for `table2`

and after the changes I need to make the entity for `table2` becomes

```
public class EnvironmentDetails
{
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_AppUserMachine", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(EnvironmentTypeId))]
    public virtual EnvironmentTypes EnvironmentType { get; set; }

    public int EnvironmentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

creating the migration gives:

```
public partial class DenormaliseEnvironmentTypeFromEnvironmentDetails : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false);
        CreateIndex("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", "dbo.EnvironmentTypes", "EnvironmentTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentType");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentType", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        DropForeignKey("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", "dbo.EnvironmentTypes");
        DropIndex("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", new[] { "EnvironmentTypeId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId");
    }
}
```

which works fine for an empty database, but if I have data in `table2` then running the migration throws an error to do with the foreign key constraint.

My thoughts were that I should populate the new `EnvironmentTypeId` column based on the data that is there before, so I tried to amend the migration to add a `defaultValueSql` parameter to the `ColumnBuilder`:

```
AddColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(select [EnvironmentTypeId] from [dbo].[EnvironmentTypes] where [dbo].[EnvironmentTypes].[EnumId] = [EnvironmentType])"));
```

however this gives the error

```
Error Number:1046,State:1,Class:15
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Is there any way to perform this migration without a loss of data (or integity)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the answer by @Александр-Пашкин I managed to manually amend the migration to maintain the existing data.  The migration I finally used looked like:

```
CreateTable("tmp", c => new
{
    DetailsId = c.Int(),
    TypeId = c.Int()
});
Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[tmp] select d.Id as DetailsId, t.EnvironmentTypeId as TypeId from [dbo].[EnvironmentDetails] d inner join [dbo].[EnvironmentTypes] t on d.EnvironmentType = t.EnumId");
AddColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 1));
CreateIndex("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId");
AddForeignKey("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentTypeId", "dbo.EnvironmentTypes", "EnvironmentTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
DropColumn("dbo.EnvironmentDetails", "EnvironmentType");
Sql("UPDATE [dbo].[EnvironmentDetails] SET [EnvironmentTypeId] = (SELECT t.[TypeId] from [dbo].[tmp] t where t.DetailsId = Id)");
DropTable("tmp");
```

So involves creating a temporary table to hold the link between the tables based on current data

amending the data model as required

then populating the existing `table2` from the temporary table

finally dropping the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using Sql method of DbMigration and remove defaultValueSql

```
Sql("select [EnvironmentTypeId] from [dbo].[EnvironmentTypes] 
     where [dbo].[EnvironmentTypes].[EnumId] = [EnvironmentType]");
```